# Ubuntu and Dual Graphics Cards

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel-hd

I've been following the development of dual graphic card support.

I see that there are articles here:
[Community Help Wiki / Hybrid Graphics](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics)

and here:
[Hybrid Graphics](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/HybridGraphics)

The newer article states that support for dual graphics cards requires hardware that is muxless.

Has anyone had any luck using Ubuntu with computers that have a hardware mux for switching between graphics cards?

Comment: I never bothered: When I need to drive an HDMI port (To watch a movie on my TV), I reboot, enable NVidia in the BIOS and then continue the boot.  Afterwards I revert back.  However, I've read about [Bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee), so that is something else you might look at.

Answer (score 0):

#### [Read here about installing Hybrid](http://linuxsagas.digitaleagle.net/2014/05/20/ubuntu-14-04-hybrid-graphics/)

[image: Quick Switch]

[image: X Server settings]